# Why does inline void foo() { ... } in a common header just work?

Tags: c, static, inline

Consider the use of `inline` in C99, with various options (extern'ing, static inline etc), as described [here](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html), for example.

I don't understand why the C standard does not allow for just using

```
void inline foo() { do_stuff(); }
```

in a common header file, and for that to work everywhere. Why do I have to add `static`? Isn't what I want clear enough already?

Comment: Generally you *don't* need `static`, except in old versions of gcc.

Comment: @PaulR: I don't think version 4.8.3 is old, and I just got burned slightly for trying a non-static inline....

Comment: That's odd - I thought this only happened with gcc 2.x and maybe 3.x, and even then only with debug builds (`-O0`). Are you compiling with `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` or something else ? What error are you getting ?

Comment: OK - does it also happen with optimisation enabled (`-O3`) ? And what about if you add `-std=c99` (or is that the default now anyway ?) ? Also what is the error message ?

Comment: @PaulR correction... it's actually `gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  a.o b.o c.o  -lpthread  -m64 -Wl,--rpath=\$ORIGIN/../lib   -Wl,-soname -Wl,d.so.0 -o d.so.0.1.0`

Comment: And I get `a.o: In function 'log_2': /some/where.h:470: multiple definition of 'log_2' \n b.o:/some/where.h:470: first defined here`

Comment: OK - yes - that's the old gcc behaviour - you get link errors for multiple definitions without `static`. I thought his had been fixed but evidently not. I don't know any other compiler that has this quirk.

Comment: Exactly. No `static` is required for inline functions in header files in C99. If your implementation produces linker errors, it means that the implementation is broken.

Comment: Please have a look at your code you have the function declared extern in more than one source file. This is why you get the multiple definition errors. You should declare the function extern in just one source file

Comment: @SebastianCabot: I don't have the function declared extern anywhere. Why should I? I mean, I "told" the compiler to inline it; so I don't want it to exist as object code anywhere; why do I have to do anything else? That's the point of my question.

Comment: Did you actually read my answer? You should declare it extern just once if you don't want it to be static inline

Comment: Show a minimal working compilable sample where your problem happens. It seems that your problem is not related to your question

Answer (score 1):

From the [gcc site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html):

> When an inline function is not static, then the compiler must assume
>   that there may be calls from other source files; since a global symbol
>   can be defined only once in any program, the function must not be
>   defined in the other source files, so the calls therein cannot be
>   integrated. Therefore, a non-static inline function is always compiled
>   on its own in the usual fashion.

What does it mean for you. You cannot define the inline function in the header since it will mean that it will be defined from different translation units (.c files that include it).
Once it is defined `static inline` then each c file that includes the header will have its own copy of the function.

**EDIT**

gcc behaves correctly. Inline functions were added to the standard with the introduction of C99. The standard is somewhat ambiguous and states:

> Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function.  For a
>   function with external linkage, the following restrictions apply: If a
>   function is declared with an inline function specifier, then it shall
>   also be defined in the same translation unit.  If all of the file
>   scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the
>   inline function specifier without extern,  then the definition in that
>   translation unit is an inline definition.  An inline definition does
>   not provide an external definition for the function, and does not
>   forbid an external definition in another translation unit.  An inline
>   definition provides an alternative to an external definition, which a
>   translator may use to implement any call to the function in the same
>   translation unit.  It is unspecified whether a call to the function
>   uses the inline definition or the external definition.

What it actually means is that when the compiler sees the inline keyword cannot know if the function was already defined in another translation unit (This will be known only during linking). Now most compilers gcc included will not inline a function without optimizations turned on. So if you try to use an inline function when compiling with -O0 the compiler issues a real call to the function (It assumes it is defined in a another file then the one it is currently compiling). Now when the linker encounters the call it tries to find the function in all compiled objects but fails (because the compiler didn't create a body for the function neither did it inline it - the standard says it doesn't have to create a body for the function and that it can assume there is a definition some where). This is why you get the error: `undefined reference to f` when you link your project. This is the correct behavior when compiling with -std=c99 onward. It also means that if you want an inline function to have abody you must declare it external only once **BUT** you must also provide the definition within the same translation unit you declared the function with extrnal linkage.

So in order to get your code to work correctly according to the standard you should do the following:

in the h file just do as you would expect.

```
inline void f(){ /*DO SOMETHING*/}
```

And in just one of your code files (.c files) you do:

```
extern inline void f();
```

What happens is that now the compiler encounters in just one translation unit both body definition (taken from the header) and a declaration that says it should exist an external definition somewhere and in accordance with the standard creates one for the function.

So the standard says that any function with internal linkage can be declared inline and that the compiler should generate a body for it. In C a function is considered to have internal linkage only when adding the static keyword.
This is why `static inline void f()` works. Without the static keyword the compiler assumes that the function has external linkage and that is why just specifying `inline void f()` without also adding `extern inline void f()` in just one source file will not work.

Comment: So, is this gcc-specific? Because, if I inlined the function, I would think different compilers should assume "oh, ok, there's no real duplicate object code anyway". Also, you've just explained that gcc behaves that way, but the question remains - why?

Comment: I will edit my answer with explenation and show you how to do it correctly

Comment: @einpoklum I saw you wrote some more in the comments. Look there are two separate questions. The first is how to correctly use inline functions in C. The second is about gcc and how to compile correctly. In the comments you showed only the call to the linker and not the call to the compiler so I don't really know why you have multiple definitions. The reason static is taking them away is that when you add static every source gets its own copy of the function

Comment: @einpoklum In order to verify I have created a test project containing two source files and one h with an inline function. with the guidelines given above - gcc works as expected

Answer (score 0):

> ...C standard does not allow for just using...

That's completely wrong. Your question is based on some incorrect/outdated/compiler specific premise, which has nothing to do with C standard. In C language you don't need `static` when putting `inline` function in header file. An `inline` definition without an explicitly specified `extern` keyword does not form an *external definition* for that function. For that reason `inline` definition without `static` cannot trigger any multiple-definition-related errors (if that's what you are afraid of).

Moreover, the link that you posted clearly says that C standard does not say anything implied in your question. It says that *GCC compiler* implements `inline` differently from what's required by C standard (probably referring to an older version of GCC).

In other words, from C language point of view you *can* (and should) put

```
inline void foo() { do_stuff(); }
```

in the header file. No `static` required.

Comment: static is actually required since gcc actually corrected it's behavior. The document he quotes is old. (Or adding an external linkage specifier in one translation unit)

Comment: @Sebastian Cabot: It is nice to know that GCC has corrected its behavior, but I still don't see what makes you think that `static` is somehow required here. `static` would give that function internal linkage. If you want internal linkage, you specify `static`. However, it is in no way "required". C language does include the concept of inline function with external linkage. And yes, you define such function in header files without `static`.

Comment: Look at my answer. The standard clearly specifies that every internal linkage function can be made inline and that the compilers should generate  a body for it. As you know the header once included becomes part of the .c file. So if you declare it static inline the compiler will correctly generate the body in each source file that includes the header and no errors will occur during linkage

Comment: @Sebastian Cabot: That's great, but "...every internal linkage function..."? Why do you keep insisting on internal linkage? Nobody said so far that they want a function with internal linkage. You are basically saying that "it will work with `static`". That's nice. But what I'm saying is that it will work without `static` as well. Again, it is a question of linkage: what linkage do you want your function to have? No error will occur during linkage if you use it without `static`. If your implementation produces linkage errors without `static`, the implementation is broken.

Comment: You are partially right. It will work without static in one of two cases: One, you compile with aggressive optimizations turned on and your function can actually be inlined. Two, you specify inline extern void f(); in exactly one source file that includes the header. You should really read my answer, it's very thorough

Comment: @Sebastian Cabot: Well, that is true that an external definition for the function (with explicit `extern inline`) should be present somewhere as well. But that does not justify blatantly asserting that "`static` is required" in this case.

Comment: In the case that the OP asked about. Just putting an inline function in a header will not work. That is why he asked the question in the first place. You need to add certain things to your code for it to link. So although you can have a header with an inline function without static you should add static unless you make sure there is an actual definition somewhere

Comment: @AnT: Why? Why should it? My intentions are perfectly clear with the line of code I put in the common .h file. I don't want to have to say "Expect something extern" anywhere (not to mention the issue of needing to arbitrarily create asymmetry).

Comment: @einpoklum: I'm a bit confused about this, in the very same way as the page you linked. The page says "The standard is vague on this point. [...] Unfortunately this doesn't really make clear whether this external definition must actually exist." I also don't see a definitive answer anywhere on whether the *external definition* is required (as Sebastian Cabot claims). I tend to believe it is not supposed to required as long as plain `inline` definition is visible at the point of the call.

Comment: People like saying the standard is ambiguous. But in reality it is not. If you are really interested look it up and read it for yourself. Inline doesn't even mean that the compiler should inline anything just that it should try to call the function as fast as possible.

Comment: @Sebastian Cabot: My knowledge of the standard goes far beyond that of people who simply "like saying the standard is ambiguous". No, I don't like saying that the standard is ambiguous. Which means that when I do, it means that there's a very good chance that it is really ambiguous. And indeed, if you really "look it up and read it for yourself", you will certainly discover that there quite a few well-known defects in the standard (including ambiguities).